# do not let me enter the server with the private key

Tags: centos, ssh, putty

I launch my command from cmd:

```
start putty -load 192.168.1.200 -i C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\id_rsa.ppk"
```

it goes out to me to enter private password in putty:

```
Using username "root".
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Passphrase for key "imported-openssh-key":
```

how can i do it so that i can enter alone and not enter the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by configuring the sshd_config so:

```
PermitRootLogin yes


AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys


PasswordAuthentication no


ChallengeResponseAuthentication no



UsePAM no

X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use SSH-Agent where your key should be stored, for PuTTY it could be Pageant. You could read more in this [article](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter9.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is because your key file itself has a passphrase. Use an SSH client that can store key passwords or generate a new keypair without a passphrase on the server. Your server is *not* asking you for password.